# Close Fancybox and load clicked id/a on "main page", when clicked inside Fancybox

Tags: jquery, iframe, fancybox

I am wondering if the following is possible:

I have an a `href` with an `ID`. When clicked it opens an Fancybox `iframe`.

Now when you *click* an `<a href..> / ID` on the Fancybox `iframe`, the Fancybox closes and loads the clicked link on the main page.

I know I can use

```
   'afterClose':function () {
        ...
    },
```

but how do I get this around?
Thanks for ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, links inside a fancybox iframe should open in the **main page** and not inside the fancybox iframe.

If so, suppose you have these links inside the iframed page :

```
<a href="http://example.com">open example</a>
<a href="http://another.com">open another</a>
<a href="http://someother.com">open someother</a>
```

When you `click` either of them, they should open (unless there are X-Frame restrictions) the new page in the same opened fancybox, shouldn't they?

I would create in the *parent* page (from where you call the fancybox iframe) a function that gets the `href` of each link inside the `iframe` as parameter and opens them in the main window when called like :

```
function setHREF(href){
    jQuery.fancybox.close(); // call method to close fancybox
    window.location.href = href; // redirects page to new href
}
```

Then add an `onclick` *attribute* to each `<a>` link (inside the iframed page) that passes the `href` to the *function* in the *parent* page like :

```
<a onclick="event.preventDefault();parent.setHREF(this.href)" href="http://example.com">open example</a>
<a onclick="event.preventDefault();parent.setHREF(this.href)" href="http://another.com">open another</a>
<a onclick="event.preventDefault();parent.setHREF(this.href)" href="http://someother.com">open someother</a>
```

**Important** : it's assumed you have control over the iframed page so you can edited and both, the parent page and the iframed page are under the same domain.

Comment: Thank you! That was really nice explained.

Comment: But instead of jQuery.fancybox.close(); I took parent.$.fancybox.close();, the other one didn't work.